# Showing total of loaded values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net

Hi I have form that lists certain values of sales. After loading sales I want to show the total of all the values. Right now it works fine but I have to change some value and it will show the total. What I want to do is also to show the total upon loading the form.

```
           <form id="sales" action="" >                 
                <table class="salesTable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        {{#each items}}
                 <tr class="">
                     <td><input type="abd" name="{{=id}}" id="{{=id}}" value='{{=sales}}'  onchange="updateTotal(this.form)" /></td>                                               
                 </tr>        
                <tr>
                    <td style="font:bold">Total</td>
                    <td><input type="abd" name="sum" onfocus="this.blur()" readyonly  value=""/>         </td>
                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

jquery function is

```
function updateTotal(formObj) {
            var total = 0;
            total += parseInt(formObj.s1011.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.s1018.value, 10)
            total += parseInt(formObj.s1019.value, 10)         
            formObj.sum.value = total
        }
```

Please let me know how can i change it so it will also show the total of the values when form is leaded. Thanks

Comment: what about to call `updateTotal` in `window.onload` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function when DOM is loaded and ready.

E.g with jQuery:

```
$(function() { // This is executed when DOM is ready
    var form = $("#sales")[0]; // get the form's DOM node
    updateTotal(form); // call the function on it
});
```